# How to set purview that the product only can edit for publisher

Tags: php

This is on my listProduct to send the id for edit. When i change the test.com/editProduct.php?id=1 to id=2 which is not under my product but i can edit too.

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function editProduct(id){
    window.location="editProduct.php?id="+id;
  }
</script>
```

---

Any ideas to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to write some code on editProduct.php page. check the product is yours or not through product id.

Comment: Welcome .... please vote...  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function editProduct(id){
    var url = "editProduct.php?id="+id;
    location.href = url;
  }
</script>
```

i hope it will be helpful.

Comment: the function still like old one. any other idea ?

Comment: alert(id); in script.can you get any result in alert?

Comment: I can get the id. But the function also like before one. But i ady use the above way to solve it.